# PHP String Replace with end of string

Tags: php, string

I need to replace some string to end of string or cut the string when he got ";" sign?

Im trying but it doesnt work :

```
$string = "Hello World; lorem ipsum dolor";
$string = str_replace(";","\0",$string);
echo $string; //I want the result is "Hello World"
```

Comment: You might take a look at [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: What happens if there is no ";" in the string?

Comment: Too many duplicates, why didn't someone close this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two ways to do that, but in the end it's all pretty similar:

### replacing the part

As you use `str_replace` in your question and you put a NUL byte in there to end a string (like perhaps in C), what you're probably looking for is [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/substr_replace):

```
$string = "Hello World; lorem ipsum dolor";
$pos    = strpos($string, ";");
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    $string = substr_replace($string, "", $pos);
}
var_dump($string); // string(11) "Hello World"
```

### extracting the part

This is was most of the other answers suggest. Here is even another alternative function for that, you're perhaps looking for the [`strstr()` function](http://php.net/strstr):
    $result = strstr($string, ";", true);

This function call with the third parameter set to true returns all of `$string` until the needle (second parameter) "`;`" is found (excluding it).

Full example:

```
$string = "Hello World; lorem ipsum dolor";
$result = strstr($string, ";", true);
var_dump($result); // string(11) "Hello World"
```

Depending on how it should work when "`;`" is part or not part of the string, you need to add the needed once if you want to return the full string:

```
$result = strstr("$string;", ";", true);
```

This is similar if you operate with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos), you have to deal with `FALSE` case as well.

Comment: Ah, forgot that `strstr()` has 3 parameter! Very clean and simple answer!

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = "Hello World; lorem ipsum dolor";
    echo $string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ";"));

?>
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the string with `;` and get first element from the returned array (it will always have at least one entry).

```
echo explode(';', $string, 2)[0];
```

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 2):

cut the rest from ";" on with strpos from http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php

```
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ";"));
```